# xlsxwriter: how formulas insert

Tags: excel, formula, xlsxwriter

I'm new to xlsxwriter, so maybe it's a problem of misunderstanding.
I write create a workbook with some worksheet. Al works fine.
Only: I'm not able to insert a correct formula.

My problem, as I understand: I had to insert the English translation:

```vb
=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGEIF($daten.A:A,A2,$daten.E:E)),#N/A,AVERAGEIF($daten.A:A,A2,$daten.E:E))
```

After writing, LibreOffice is able to open, but the formula do not work. Cells were final with "0" !!

After checking, these formula is displayed in Libreoffice:

```vb
=WENN(ISTFEHLER(MITTELWERTWENN($daten.a:a;A2;$daten.e:e));#NV;MITTELWERTWENN($daten.a:a;A2;$daten.e:e))
```

If I do a change, e->E for example, and press enter, all works fine.

Excel on Windows told me on the workbook, that there is a mistake on the sheet...

I expect, its my issue, but how to solve it ?

Thank's for any reply

JR

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet? `$daten.`?

Comment: I checked the hint: Yes, there is the issue! The "$" was not writen by my application! Seems a "automatic" inside xlsx/execl. But how to reduce the char ?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably more than one issue here.

The first is that the formula needs to be in English (you got that part) but also have US English syntax. See the following section of the XlsxWriter docs for an explanation: [Non US Excel functions and syntax](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#non-us-excel-functions-and-syntax).

It should probably be something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGEIF(daten!A:A,A2,daten!E:E)),#N/A,AVERAGEIF(daten!A:A,A2,daten!E:E))
```

If that isn't correct then the best thing to do is to work out the correct formula in Excel and then translate it from German to English+Syntax using the tool from the docs above: https://en.excel-translator.de/language/ or [examine](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-formula-errors) the formula in the save Excel file.

The issue with the 0 values is explained in the next section of the above docs. For LibreOffice workarounds see the following FAQ: [Q. Why do my formulas show a zero result in some, non-Excel applications?](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-why-do-my-formulas-show-a-zero-result-in-some-non-excel-applications)

It is worth reading the entire chapter on [Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html) in the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot.    The background of "0" was written. I check and understood. 
But the Formel/syntax was translate  by the recomended tool.
It seems, during saving the tablename "daten" were translated to "$daten"   . Why ?
If I write datenTEST, this sheet does not exists, works.   But sheet "daten" ist still used by formula.
Maybe I should write the "daten" sheht after  my sheet ?   Makes no sense for me.

Comment: What do you mean: "The first is that the formula needs to be in English (you got that part) but also have US English syntax."

Is there a issue ?